# Building Dockerfile in subfolder

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, aws-cdk

I am attempting to build a Visual Studio Dockerfile as part of a AWS CDK (C#) based deployment, due to lacking foresight, the `aws-cdk` project locks the context directory for the `docker build` as `.` ([see here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/cdk-assets/lib/private/docker.ts#L61)).

```
public async build(options: BuildOptions) {
    const buildCommand = [
      'build',
      ...flatten(Object.entries(options.buildArgs || {}).map(([k, v]) => ['--build-arg', `${k}=${v}`])),
      '--tag', options.tag,
      ...options.target ? ['--target', options.target] : [],
      ...options.file ? ['--file', options.file] : [],
      ...options.networkMode ? ['--network', options.networkMode] : [],
      ...options.platform ? ['--platform', options.platform] : [],
      '.',
    ];
    await this.execute(buildCommand, { cwd: options.directory });
  }
```

The problem is that when building a Visual Studio based Dockerfile the context directory must be the solution directory (aka `..`) ([see here for the spec](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/cdk-assets/lib/private/docker.ts#L61)).

> To build a containerized solution from the command line, you can usually use the command docker build  for each project in the solution. You provide the build context argument. The build context for a Dockerfile is the folder on the local machine that's used as the working folder to generate the image. For example, it's the folder that you copy files from when you copy to the container. In .NET Core projects, use the folder that contains the solution file (.sln). Expressed as a relative path, this argument is typically ".." for a Dockerfile in a project folder, and the solution file in its parent folder. For .NET Framework projects, the build context is the project folder, not the solution folder.

`aws-cdk` does provide some facility to set the working directory but it appears something is wrong with the build when i do this.

```
var asset = new DockerImageAsset(this, "DockerImage", new DockerImageAssetProps
{
    Directory = "src/",
    File = "./my-proj-folder/Dockerfile"
});
```

```
[100%] fail: docker build --tag cdkasset-f8496b3dff58cbf812e7dd54e75951875bd214697ff8f2ece1708e20b46c9072 --file ./my-proj-folder/Dockerfile . exited with error code 1: #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:a1ac387515b3f5a15bafcf29c84d0211dc051965b2e83be31d4e979c1941c9ad
#1 transferring dockerfile: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:cd10dc57528ad97b7a8d5f32a381d6917b3557895a47741bc37a03d7d2498448
#2 transferring context:
#2 CANCELED
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2254455160/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

 ❌ Building assets failed: Error: Building Assets Failed: Error: Failed to build one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at buildAllStackAssets (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:374:115279)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:374:143496)
    at async exec4 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.15.0\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:429:51795)
```

Is it possible to specify a Dockerfile to build that is *LOWER* than the current context directory?

Comment: `open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2254455160/Dockerfile: no such file or directory` this seems to be a new problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Looks like the `.dockerignore` that Visual Studio auto generates has the following definition.

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

My command is actually correct, what happens is the `.dockerignore` is picked up and then applied from the CONTEXT directory point of view. This means my `Dockerfile` then gets ignored as that file is picked up next during the build. Then everything goes kaboom after that.

If i comment out the `**/Dockerfile*` from the ignore file it starts working...